# тестовое задание на позицию тестировщик

Tags: тестирование

Подал заявку на вакансию тестировщик, спустя какое-то время прислали тестовое задание, в котором были задачи составить кейс-тесты и найти ошибку на скриншоте. Насчет скриншотов не очень понял, помогите пожалуйста в нахождении ошибок.

[image: Экран электронного курса. Какие ошибки на экране.]

[image: Экран электронного курса. Какие ошибки на экране.]

[image: Экран электронного курса. Какие ошибки на экране.]

Comment: Не кейс-тесты, а тест-кейсы.

Comment: Ну, вот, например, грубая ошибка: "до 3-х лет". Так сокращать нельзя, правильно "до 3 лет".

Comment: У вас на красном слайде шапки нет

Comment: Ужасное задание. Это для кого тест, для ребенка на внимательность, - "Ой тут есть двоеточие, а тут нет!". А кейс-тесты - это реальность, это простое тестирование по алгоритму, которое могут выполнить не только тех. специалисты, но и обычные менеджеры. **Главная ошибка на скиншотах - идиотский дизайн**